# Automatically switch between \theenumi, \theenumii, and \theenumiii based on \@enumdepth

Tags: enumerate

I am trying to reformat an enumerated value depending on whether I am "grading" or not, and I have a working solution, but I would like to know would be how to automatically switch between `\theenumi`, `\theenumii`, and `\theenumiii` based on `\@enumdepth` in the minimum working example that I have posted below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen, amsmath, tikz, enumerate}

\newif\ifgrading
\gradingtrue

\newcommand*\circleAns[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt,color=blue] (char) {#1};}}

\makeatletter        
\newcommand{\itemAns}{
    \ifgrading
        \stepcounter{enum\romannumeral\@enumdepth}
        \item[\circleAns{\textcolor{blue}{\theenumi)}}]
    \else \item
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[a)]
    \item 
    \itemAns
    \item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I tried using `\theenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth` instead of `\theenumii`, similar to what I did with `\stepcounter{enum\romannumeral\@enumdepth}`, which didn't work though I think I understand why.  If anyone has any suggestions for how to implement this solution better and update based on the level, I am very open to suggestions.

--------------------------- EDIT

Using Donald Arseneau's solution as a basis, I've modified my implementation to also include the label automatically:  `\textcolor{ForestGreen}{\@nameuse{label\@enumctr}}`
So the code

```
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
    \item 
    \itemAns
    \item 
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[a.]
    \item 
    \item 
    \itemAns
\end{enumerate}
```

produces
[image]
So it has the functionality I need it to.  If anyone knows a simple way of recentering the circled items, let me know but otherwise I'm very happy with the result!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\@nameuse{ }` or `\csname \endcsname`.

```
\textcolor{blue}{\@nameuse{theenum\romannumeral\@enumdepth})}
```

But since you already know about `\@enumdepth` and use it, you probably have seen `\@enumctr` which will simplify usage

```
\textcolor{blue}{\@nameuse{the\@enumctr})}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you for your help!